# Javaparser: get generic class of a method return type like List<MyClass>

Tags: java, javaparser

I'm processing a Java source file using the java-parser library.

**I have this situation in the analyzed source code:**

```
 List<Allergen> getList() {
        return EnumSet.allOf(Allergen.class).stream()
                .filter(this::isAllergicTo)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

I need to access the generic class of the List return type ( **Allergen** in this example)

I'm using an extension of **VoidVisitorAdapter** class in my analyzer

**Here an extract of the code:**

```
public class PlaceholderNormalizer extends VoidVisitorAdapter<String> {

 ...
 ...
 
 
 @Override
    public void visit(MethodDeclaration n, String arg) {
        logger.debug("MethodDeclaration: {}", n.getName().asString());
        logger.debug(" --- " + n.getTypeAsString());  // prints: List<Allergen>
    
    // DO SOME STUFF
        super.visit(n, arg);
    }
  
  ...
  ...
}
```

I can obtain a **Type** object of the node **MethodDeclaration** using `n.getType()`

But, I don't understand how to retrieve the **Allergen** class.

Please I need some help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of this method the `n.getType` will return instance of `ClassOrInterfaceType`. To get to generic parameter you can obtain it as this type and use [`ClassOrInterfaceType::getTypeArguments`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.github.javaparser/javaparser-core/3.5.0/com/github/javaparser/ast/type/ClassOrInterfaceType.html#getTypeArguments--) method :

```
@Override
public void visit(MethodDeclaration n, String arg) {
    Type type = n.getType();

    if(type instanceof ClassOrInterfaceType) {
        ClassOrInterfaceType classOrInterfaceType = type.asClassOrInterfaceType();
        Optional<NodeList<Type>> typeArguments = classOrInterfaceType.getTypeArguments();

        //list of arguments might have different length
        typeArguments.ifPresent(types -> System.out.println(types.get(0)));
    }
        // DO SOME STUFF
     super.visit(n, arg);
}
```

This will print `Allergen`.